# How can I get the output from the function inside the class?

Tags: python, class

I saw the code below in the book, didn't write it myself. I can only get "3 5" when I run it. I want to see an output of the math.hypot function. How can I get it?

```
class Point:

    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float) -> None:
        self.move(x, y)

    def move(self, x: float, y: float) -> None:
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def reset(self) -> None:
        self.move(0, 0)

    def calculate_distance(self, other: "Point") -> float:
        return math.hypot(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)

point = Point(3, 5)
print(point.x, point.y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'd need two points.

Then you [call the function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

```
point1 = Point(3, 5)
point2 = Point(4, 5)

print(point1.calculate_distance(point2))
```

You'll also need to add `import math` at the top of your Point class

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. However, I write the code like this and it still worked. I just want to to know the difference between this code and the previous version.

`import math
class Point:

    def __init__(self, x: float, y: float) -> None:
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def calculate_distance(self, other: "Point") -> float:
        return math.hypot(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)

point1 = Point(3, 5)
point2 = Point(7, 5)

print(point1.calculate_distance(point2))`

Comment: Dont understand your question. That looks like the same code. You only changed the second point coordinates

Comment: Yeah. They're the same actually. I removed def move() and def reset() functions. Then I write self.x = x self.y = y inside of def __init__() function and it still worked. I wonder what's the difference between these two codes? I mean, can I write it like the last one I write?

Comment: Oh. The init function is a constructor.... It's fine and does the same thing as the move function, sure... Please refer Python tutorials on best practices of writing classes